# Remove tuples in a set with certain value efficiently

Tags: python, set, tuples

I have a set of tuples, e.g. set_of_tuples = {(1,2}, (1,3), (1,), (4,3)} and I want to delete all tuples that contain for example a `1` and I want to know how many that are. How could this be done efficiently?

My approach:

```
set_of_tuples={(1,2),(1,3),(1,),(4,3)}
to_be_removed = set()
i=0
for val in set_of_tuples:
    if 1 in val:
        i=i+1
        to_be_removed.add(val)
set_of_tuples = set_of_tuples-to_be_removed
```

Comment: Have you tried `set_of_tuples = {s for s in set_of_tuples if 1 not in s}`?

Comment: And if you want to know how many were removed, save the length of the set before and subtract the resulting length.

Comment: No...thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

My code is in this link
please see this !!!  :)

https://onlinegdb.com/HJ8RX2LNO